# Tabulator - Header Filters - disable spinner

Tags: tabulator

I am using the Min Max Custom Header Filter

Is there any option to disable the 'up/down spinner' and simply enter a min & max values

If not does anyone know a workaround - I have limited workspace and the spinner consumes each input box when the column is narrowed.

Comment: Please make sure you post either a snippet of code or a link to a JS fiddle so that people can give you specific advice

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the line where it sets the `type` property on the input elements to set it to `text` instead of `number`

so the line:

```js
start.setAttribute("type", "number");
```

should become:

```js
start.setAttribute("type", "text");
```

Comment: Understood, but wouldn't I lose my ability to format numbers - my numbers range from single digits to several millions (need commas for readability) - which is why the up/down spinner has little value